# Need to insert href="#" like in <a href="#"> in asp:linkbutton

Tags: asp.net

I need to insert href="#" like in  in asp:linkbutton. please let me know how I can do this..
 Thanks
Mithilesh

Comment: If really need that. then replace the Linkbutton with Hyperlink and Place the required # as Navigate URL

Answer (score 0):

Href property in linkbutton is used for raising a postback, if you don't want to use postback, you can use  tag instead directly. Or if you still want to use linkbutton, try the code with JQuery library which replaces the function that raises the postback with '#'.

```
$(function(){
     $('a').attr('href', '#');
});
```

Comment: why does this feel like a hack on top of a hack?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, so that's why I suggest using hyperlink first :)